# Woocommerce Payment form example

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I'm trying to create a form using woocommerce that allows a user to 
pay an insurance premium. The user can specify the amount they wish to pay.
The form will be simple, a few fields and the amount the user can specify.

Would anyone have a recommendation on how best to do this?

Thanks

Comment: Please post the code that you have tried so far to achieve your goal.

Comment: [Customizing checkout fields using actions and filters](https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/tutorial-customising-checkout-fields-using-actions-and-filters/)